# Need help stopping MSXML from adding namespaces

Tags: xml, msxml, msxml4

I am using MSXML 4 to generate the following xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Parent_Element xmlns="http://1">
    <Child_One>
        <Child_Two xmlns="http://2">
            <Child_Three>
            </Child_Three>
        </Child_Two>
    </Child_One>
</Parent>
```

However the output from my IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr always includes a namespace for Child_Three:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Parent_Element xmlns="http://1">
    <Child_One>
        <Child_Two xmlns="http://2">
            <Child_Three xmlns="http://1">
            </Child_Three>
        </Child_Two>
    </Child_One>
</Parent>
```

My understanding is that this behavior is part of the XML standard, but the system receiving the xml rejects it if the extra namespace is present.  It will also reject the xml if there is an empty namespace (i.e. xmlns="").

Is there anyway in MSXML to avoid adding or removing the namespace for Child_Three?

Comment: `Child_Three` belongs to what namespace?

Comment: By default, since no namespace is declared for Child_Three it uses the document namespace: http://1.  My understanding is that this is a W3C XML standard.

Comment: if `Two` gets a default namespace (without a prefix) every child will use that namespace; so `Three` will be `http://2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

1) I had a defect where the document namespace was used instead of the namespace in the parent node.

2) With the fix from #1, I ended up with an empty namespace (xmlns="").  To corect this I had to set the namepace when the node is created.  Before I was creating the node and then added the xmlns attribute in a separate call.

Before:

```
pNode->createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, name, "");
pAttrib = pNode->createAttribute("xmlns")
pAttrib->put_NodeValue(namespace)
```

Now:

```
pNode->createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, name, "namespace");
```

Answer (score 0):

MSXML will represent exactly the namespaces you tell it to represent.

From your quotation, it looks as if you created the child3 node with a namespace of http://1, and you need to create it with a namespace of http://2.

Comment: I tried that and I get the following:

<?xml version="1.0">
<Parent_Element xmlns="http://1">
    <Child_One>
        <Child_Two xmlns="http://2">
            <Child_Three xmlns="http://2">
            </Child_Three>
        </Child_Two>
    </Child_One>
</Parent>

The issue is that the namespace is included in the output.  Whatever he namespace is, I cannot include it in the output.

Comment: You need to post code. However, no valid XML reader is allowed to reject that 'excess' namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. The issue is that MSXML cannot handle broken namespaces...

I had a situation recently where in the highest level tag, there was a xmlns="http://...", but this was wrong. It should have been: xmlns:xsd="http://...".

Once i fixed that in the topmost xml tag, i could insert xml tags into documents without seeing the xmlns="" everywhere.

Interestingly when you write a XML document from the start, create the hierarchy of tags, you wont get the xmlns="" tags.